# switchee syntax error: {exp:switchee}

Tags: switchee

I am getting a syntax error when trying to set-up switchee on a new ee site. I am in 3.5.10 and I am using switchee v. 3.0. This is the first time using it in 3.x have used it several time on two ee 2.x site with out a problem. Not sure what is going on. 
Here is the code:

```
{exp:switchee variable="{segment_2}" parse="inward"}
{case value=""}
    {embed="includes/.page-content-landing"}
{/case}

{case default="yes"}
    {embed="includes/.page-content-detail"}
{/case}
{/exp:switchee}
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

If you are only choosing between two values, I'd replace `{switchee}` with a simple `{if}` statement - and perhaps save on an addon.  `{switchee}` was a particular solution to a weakness in [pre-2.9 versions of EE](https://github.com/croxton/Switchee), and now really only useful if you value the syntax options it provides.

So I'd try something like this:

```
{if segment_2 == ""}
    {embed="includes/.page-content-landing"}
{if:else}
    {embed="includes/.page-content-detail"}
{/if}
```

Also, if your use of `embed` is simply to drop in template code (which seems likely as you are not passing any embed variables) you might also want to consider replacing them with layout variables.

HTH

Comment: This work ... so I should just drop using {exp:switchee}

Comment: Yep - I would.  The fewer addons you use, the less messy things are when EE gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have it installed correctly.